# Angular universal rendering for some routes only

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I was playing with angular universal a bit but cant find option to use server side rendering only for some pages like home page and render all other routes in standard angular way. I don't want to use server side rendering for private pages where SEO is not needed. I can  configure routes in express like this

```
// send all requests to Angular Universal
// if you want Express to handle certain routes (ex. for an API) make sure you adjust this
app.get('/', ngApp);
app.get('/home', ngApp);
app.get('/about', ngApp);
```

Ideally I don't want to know about NodeJs at all and configure it on angular routes config with property like serverSide: true

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  //public route, I want server rendering for SEO
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, serverSide: true },
  //private user profile page, SEO is not needed
  { path: 'user/profile/:id', component: UserProfileComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 13):

In your server.ts 
for routes you don't want to render just do as below

```
app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });

app.get('/app/**', (req, res) => {
  console.log('not rendering  app pages');
});

app.get('/auth/**', (req, res) => {
  console.log('not rendering auth page');
});
```

// All regular routes use the Universal engine

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You will need to return the index.html file for the non rendered routes, using something like:
`app.get(routePattern, (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(distFolder + '/index.html');
      });`

Comment: is it possible to combine `/app/**` and `/auth/**` in same line instead of two different code ?

Comment: @Santosh You could use regular expressions to combine /app/** and /auth/**
`app.get(/^\/(app | auth)\/(.+)/, function (req, res, next) {}`