# Angular universal only to specific routes

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to implement **angular universal**. But I want to limit SSR  only in  2 specific routes for the time being. 
The reasons are .
1) Universal is something still developing and causes some unexpected behaviors with `@angular/flex-layout`  and `nested lazy loading`

2) I don t need SEO on all pages

So i've tried something  like this

```
app.get('/campaign/*/*', (req, res) => {
   res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

});
```

But when i try to navigate in page  `/campaign/new-channel`  pages reloads forever.
The expected behavior I expect is  the page to normally without any content be rendered .

I suppose I have to do something different since node express should pass the handling of routing to angular .
Any idea how to implement this ?
The rest code of **server.ts** is copied from here https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts

P.S There is this post on **stackoverflow** [Angular universal rendering for some routes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464614/angular-universal-rendering-for-some-routes-only) but no solution is provided  .So I made this one since I don't know if  i m allowed to open new thread in answers

Answer (score 8):

Finally  `response.sendFile`  is what I was searching for

```
app.get('/campaign/new-channel', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'));
});
```

What you want is just to return the **index.html** without any rendered content

Comment: on refresh non ssr pages are not loading

Comment: showing this error `Cannot GET /user/profile/corporate`


my code is like 
```server.get('/user/profile/:type', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(join(distFolder, 'browser', 'index.html'));
    });```